# Can you overwrite app.use in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So this is pretty simple

```
var express = require('express');
var prodServices = require('./services');
//...a bunch of other vars;

var app = express();
app.use('/services', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3, middleware4, prodServices);


if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'){
   app.use('/services', require('./dev-services')); //has no effect
   // ... a bunch of other overwrites that work fine
}
```

The app has lots going on, I would very much like to keep 'development' mode changes in a single if statement on the bottom without touching any other parts of the file. 

All my other overwrites work well except for `app.use`. Re-declaring the same statement has no effect. So I overwrite every function:

```
middleware1 = middleware2 = middleware3 = middleware4 = function(req,res,next){next()};
prodServices = require('./dev-services')
```

Some of the middlewares need to run for different paths, so I would prefer to simple re-declare the `app.use('/services')` statement. Is this possible?

#### Edit

So Looked at the possible duplicate question, the middleware stack is stored in

```
app._router.stack
```

People recommend that it's best not to mess with it, so I will find a different solution. However if someone wants to answer with a way to do it anyway. I'll mark as best answer.

Comment: middlewares are not overwritten, they are added.  And, the ones that are registered first will execute first.

Comment: so no way to remove added middlewares?

Comment: If you have all your dev stuff in one place, you can call that and have it add the app.use. Like this: app.use('/services', require('./dev-services')); But you will have to pass as a param app to that file so it can do its stuff.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602578/proper-way-to-remove-middleware-from-the-express-stack

Comment: You could probably hack into the internal data structures of Express to remove middleware, but there is no published API for that and that is not the intention of its design.